# What do you use to make programming flowcharts, diagrams, etc?

Tags: drawing, diagram, project-planning

I've always just used OpenOffice Draw and it just occurred to me that there has to be something better out there.

So what do you use? Do you like it?

Bonus points for free things and for web apps.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I use [Dia](http://www.gnome.org/projects/dia/), the Diagram Editor.

> **Dia - Best Freeware Flowcharting (Visio) Tool**
>
> Dia is a free flowcharting tool,
>   similar to Microsofts Visio. It is
>   useful for building informal diagrams,
>   database diagrams and database models,
>   as well as drawing more complex charts
>   such as UML diagrams.
>
> Objects in the charts can be connected with lines and arrows in a variety of styles.
>
> Object types in Dia include AADL,
>   Assorted, BPMN, ChemEng, Chonogram,
>   Cisco, Civil, Cybernetics, Electric,
>   ER, Flowchart, FS, Gane and Sarson,
>   GRAFCET, Jigsaw, Ladder, Logic, Map,
>   isometric, MSE, Network, Pneumatic /
>   Hydrualic, RE-i*, RE-Jackson, RE_kaos,
>   SADT/IDEFO, SDL, Sybase and UML.
>
> Dia saves diagrams in several
>   formats, including XML, EPS, SVG, XFIG
>   and PNG.
>
> Diagrams in Dia can span multiple
>   pages. For a few examples of diagrams
>   created in Dia, see
>   http://live.gnome.org/Dia/Examples.
>   Dia is freeware and open source.

Answer (score 7):

Microsoft Visio is pretty much designed for this task - whilst expensive, it's very good.

Comment: I'll second that.  I get it as part of an MSDN subscription and find it useful for flowcharts, network diagrams and database diagrams.  I haven't used OpenOffice Draw so I can't compare it but Visio seems to have everything I need.

Comment: It might be good for flowcharts but it's absolutely horrible for UML, particularly sequence diagrams.

Comment: IMHO, Visio is hard to use and takes too much time to make a diagram :(

Answer (score 5):

I am using [OmniGraffle](http://www.omnigroup.com/applications/OmniGraffle/) which is not free but I don't regret buying a license at all

Comment: OmniGraffle is an excellent tool. Sadly Mac-only; I used to bring my Mac to work just for this program alone!

Answer (score 4):

For sequence diagrams I like http://www.websequencediagrams.com

Answer (score 4):

I used [mxGraph](http://www.jgraph.com/mxgraph.html) and it is very good.

Answer (score 3):

[SmartDraw](http://www.SmartDraw.com) is great. Visio is good too, but not as feature-rich.

Google Docs has also [recently added flowchart support too](https://drive.googleblog.com/2009/09/new-flowchart-shapes-and-multi-line.html).

Answer (score 2):

I use the combo [Gliffy](http://www.gliffy.com/) and [MindMeister](http://www.mindmeister.com/).

Comment: +1 for Gliffy, haven't used MindMeister.

Answer (score 2):

There's an open-source program with features similar to Visio called [Dia](http://live.gnome.org/Dia).

For UML, there's [ArgoUML](http://argouml.tigris.org/).

Answer (score 2):

There is also [Visual Paradigm for UML](http://www.visual-paradigm.com/product/vpuml/). The community edition is free for non-commercial use.

Answer (score 1):

I've used [yEd](http://www.yworks.com/en/products_yed_about.html) with some success. Never did anything real fancy with it though.

Comment: You can do fancy things with yEd, too obviously: [yEd Gallery](http://www.yworks.com/en/products_yed_gallery.html)

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to make diagrams on paper, it's cheap and much, much faster than using a computerized tool. Not so pretty for showing to others though.

Answer (score 1):

you'll find lots of similar questions with a lot of the same answers under the [flowchart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flowcharts) tag.

Answer (score 1):

[Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) is good for some type of diagrams.

Answer (score 0):

I'll throw [Freemind](http://freemind.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) on to the heap.  Not so much for flow charting, but mindmapping.  Good for high level brainstorming sessions.

Answer (score 0):

I use both [Mindmeister](http://www.mindmeister.com/) (easy to use and free) and Visio 2007 (powerful).

Answer (score 0):

OmniGraffle
http://www.omnigroup.com/applications/OmniGraffle/

This is only for the mac, and only the demo part is free, but it worth the money.

Answer (score 0):

I Like Visio, because of its extensive shapesheets and templates that come with it. If you are also interested in making Wireframes, I can recommend [the free wireframing shapesheet from GUUUI](http://www.guuui.com/issues/02_07.php).

Also, I use FreeMind for visualising tree-style relations.

Answer (score -1):

[Rational Software Modeler](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/awdtools/modeler/swmodeler/) (used to be Rational Rose).

It also comes with a Microsoft .NET Extension that allows you to do .NET code generation from certain models.

Comment: -1000, this is the worst software I've ever used